# Дефаултное значение произвольного типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, тернарный-оператор, default, void

Пытаюсь в условный оператор запихать дефаултное значение неизвестного типа. В большинстве случаев срабатывает

```
return t ? t->f() : decltype (t->f()) {};
```

Однако, если выведенным типом оказывается `void`, то получается ошибка компиляции

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘auto call(T*) [with T = smth1]’:
prog.cpp:22:11:   required from here
prog.cpp:17:12: error: compound literal of non-object type ‘void’
   return t ? t->f() : decltype (t->f()) {};
          ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Есть ли способ поместить значение прямо в условный оператор, или единственный вариант - оборачивать всё это в `if constexpr` и дублировать код?

```
if constexpr (is_void_v<decltype(t->f())>) { if (t) return t->f(); }
else return t ? x->f() : decltype(t->f()){};
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/cAlFlT

```
struct smth1
{
  void f() {}
} a1;

struct smth2
{
  int f() { return 88; }
} a2;

template <typename T> auto call(T *t)
{
  return t ? t->f() : decltype (t->f()) {};
}

int main()
{
  call(&a1);
  call(&a2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return t ? t->f() : decltype(t->f())();` - https://ideone.com/i2Q5Gz

Comment: @Harry, ну и чего не ответом?

Comment: Да стало интересно, кто-то воспользуется комментарием, чтобы сделать из него ответ, или нет - последнее время это делается регулярно :)

Comment: @Harry, ну так надо было сразу в ответ писать. А так вроде на мете рекомендация переносить в ответы?

Comment: Не знаю, не видел (впрочем, и не смотрел). После того, как по мне пару раз потоптались, что у меня такой короткий ответ, что он годится только для комментария, пока ответа на 10 строк не набирается - я предпочитаю оставить комментарий. А вообще, что-то мне чем дальше, тем меньше начинает нравиться здешняя атмосфера, только вот свалить некуда...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct smth1
{
    void f() {}
} a1;

struct smth2
{
    int f() { return 88; }
} a2;

template <typename T> auto call(T *t)
{
    return t ? t->f() :  decltype(t->f())();
}

int main()
{
    smth1* v1 = nullptr;
    smth2* v2 = nullptr;

    call(&a1);
    call(&a2);

    call(v1);
    call(v2);

    // ок, void expression
    void();
    // синтаксическая ошибка, не может быть ни zero initialization, ни compound literal, т.к. void не является complete object type
    // void{}; 

    return 0;
}
```